# Firestore where in doesnt recognize toLowerCase() on flutter The method toUpperCase() was called on null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a signup form which create an array of each user of the nickname in LowerCase and Uppercase:

```
'userArray': FieldValue.arrayUnion([nickName.toLowerCase(),nickName.toUpperCase(),nickName])
```

Now I am going to retrieve this array but when I use the method where:

```
db.collection().where('userArray', arrayContains: [nickname.toLowerCase(),nickName.toUpperCase()];
```

I got error:

```
The method toUpperCase() was called on null
```

even if I use arrayContainsAny method

Comment: And you are sure it's not because you are sometimes using `nickname` and sometimes `nickName` (note the uppercase "N")?

Comment: it was just a typing mistake here on SOF but please read below answer I maybe find it and it works

Answer (score 1):

seems I got alone the response instead of use:

```
db.collection().where('userArray', arrayContains: [nickname.toLowerCase(),nickName.toUpperCase()];
```

we need to use:

```
db.collection().where('userArray', arrayContains: ["$nickName.toLowerCase()","$nickName.toUpperCase()"];
```

anyone can confirm it is the right method?